# SAS replace character in ALL columns

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset that I have to export to a .csv-file. I have the following two contradicting requirements.

- I have to use the **semicolon** as the delimiter in the .csv-file.
- Some of the character variables are manually inputted strings from formulas, hence they may contain **semicolons**.

My solution to the above is to either escape the semicolon or to replace it with a comma.

#### How can I, in a nice, clean and efficient way use e.g. [`tranwrd`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000215027.htm) on an entire dataset?

---

My attempt:

For each variable, use the `tranwrd(.., ";", ",")` function on a variable in the data set. Update the dataset and loop through all variables. This, however, is naturally a *very* inefficient way of doing it for even semi-large datasets, since I have to do a datastep for each variable. The code for it is quite ugly, since I have to get the variable names by a few steps, but the inefficiency definitely takes the cake.

```
data test;
    input w $ c b  d  e $ f $;
    datalines4;
Aaa;; 50 11 1 222 a;s                                        
Bbb 35 12 2 250 qw                                        
Comma, 75 13 3 foo zx                                        
;;;;
run;

* Get the variable names;
proc contents data=test out=vars(keep=name type varnum) order=varnum noprint;
run;
* Sort by variable number;
proc sort data=vars;
    by varnum;
run;

* Put variable names into a space-separated string;
proc sql noprint;
    select compress(name)        
    into :name_list separated by ' '                      
    from vars;
quit;

%let len = %sysfunc(countw(&name_list));


*Initialize loop dataset;
data a;
    set test;
run;

%macro loop;
    %do i = 1 %to &len;
        %let j = %scan(&name_list,&i);

        data a(rename=(v_&j = &j) drop=&j);
            set a;
            v_&j.=compress(tranwrd(&j,";",","));
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
%loop;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I may have more elegant solution to your problem:

```
data class;
   set sashelp.class;

   array vars [*] _character_;

   do i = 1 to dim(vars);
      vars[i] = compress(tranwrd(vars[i],"a","X"));
   end;

   drop i;
run;
```

You can use `array` to reference all character columns from your data set and then loop through them.

Comment: "I may have more elegant solution" is perhaps the biggest understatement I have seen on StackOverflow to this day. I did try with the `array` but was at a loss because it needed all variables to be the same type. I did not know about `_character_` and right now it feels like you performed magic. Thank you very much; this is not just an answer to *my* question, but to the more general problem: *how do I perform the same action on an entire dataset.*

Comment: @Therkel I am glad I could help and thank for your appretiation :)

Comment: @fl0r3k when you are only changing single characters TRANSLATE would be the preferred function.

Comment: @Therkel This is the best paper on using "SAS Variable Lists" http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2011/BB05.Schreier.pdf

Comment: @data_null_ you are right. Didn't think about it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The most widely used standard for csv files whose fields can contain delimiters is to quote fields that contain them, and double up any quotes. In SAS you can do this automatically using the `dlm` and `dsd` options in a put statement:

```
data test;
    input w $ c b  d  e $ f $;
    datalines4;
Aaa;; 50 11 1 222 a;s                                        
Bbb" 35 12 2 250 qw                                        
Comma, 75 13 3 foo zx                                        
;;;;
run;

data _null_;
  set test;
  file "c:\temp\test.csv" dsd dlm=';';
  put (_ALL_) (&);
run;
```

This results in the following semicolon-delimited csv (minus a header row, but that's a separate issue):

```
"Aaa;;";50;11;1;222;"a;s"
"Bbb""";35;12;2;250;qw
Comma,;75;13;3;foo;zx
```

Sorry, didn't notice your comment about the workaround until after I posted this. I'll leave it here in case anyone finds it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Fields in a properly formatted delimited file are quoted.  PROC EXPORT will do that.  There is no need to change the data.

```
data test;
    input w $ c b  d  e $ f $;
    datalines4;
Aaa;; 50 11 1 222 a;s                                        
Bbb 35 12 2 250 qw                                        
Comma, 75 13 3 foo zx                                        
;;;;
   run;
filename FT45F001 temp;
proc export data=test outfile=FT45F001 dbms=csv;
   delimiter=';';
   run;
data _null_;
   infile FT45F001;
   input;
   list;
   run;

proc import replace datafile=FT45F001 dbms=csv out=test2;
   delimiter=';';
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc compare base=test compare=test2;
   run;
```

Comment: That was also what I thought initially, but whatever the people I supply the data to use, it does not properly escape semicolons in quoted strings. Hence why I needed the mentioned workaround.