# SAS: Replacing Non Numeric characters in SQL table

Tags: replace, sas

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
  A |  B   
1234|A1B2C   
1124|$1n7   
1342|*6675   
1189|966
```

I need to create a column C where it takes the data from column B and replaces all non numeric characters with a "9" and makes each one 5 characters long by adding 0's to the front. It should come out like this:

91929
09197
96675
00966

Any assistance would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Edit: Sorry first time posting on any forum like this and got a bit ahead of myself, I created the table using SQL to pull data from 3 other tables and am a bit more familiar with SQL than SAS, which I have only been using for a few weeks. I have tried using COMPRESS but as I read more about that it seem like it only removes the values, so I tried TRANWRD but from what I was able to figure out I would need to create an entry for each letter and symbol that could appear, ie.

```
data Work.temp;
str = b;
Alpha=tranwrd(str, "a", "9");
Alpha=tranwrd(str, "b", "9");
put Alpha;
run;
```

so then I researched some more and found [SAS replace character in ALL columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032909/sas-replace-character-in-all-columns)

based on that I used this code:

```
data temp;
   set work.temp;

   array vars [*] _character_;

   do i = 1 to dim(vars);
      vars[i] = compress(tranwrd(vars[i],"a","9"));
   end;

   drop i;
run;
```

That just returns:
|Str|B|Alpha|
|---.|-.|.-------|

(sorry about the bad formatting there, spent 30 min trying to figure out how to make the table look right with spaces but kept coming out wrong. Please imagine the -'s are spaces)

again any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: You need to post what you've tried to date. TRANSLATE or COMPRESS functions.

Comment: What does SQL have to do with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
data test;
input var1 $5.;
datalines;
A1B2C
$1n7
*6675
966
;
run;

data test1;
set test;
length var2 $5.;
regex = prxparse ("s/[^0-9|\s]/9/"); /*holds the regular expression you want to use to substitute the non-number characters*/
var2 = prxchange (regex, -1, var1); /*use this function to substitute all instances of the pattern*/
var3 = put (input (var2, best5.), z5.); /*use input and put to pad the front of the variable with 0s*/

run;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping only the digits is simple. Use the modifiers on the COMPRESS() function.

```
 c=compress(b,,'kd');
```

Padding on the left with zeros there are a number of ways to do that.

You could convert the digits to a number then write it back to a string use the Z format.

```
c=put(input(c,??5.),Z5.);
```

You could add the zeros. Using IF statement:

```
if length(c) < 5 then c=repeat('0',5-length(c)-1)||c ;
```

Or using SUBSTRN() function.

```
c=substrn('00000',1,5-length(c))||c;
```

Or have some fun with the REVERSE() function.

```
c=reverse(substr(reverse(cats('00000',c)),1,5));
```